# Do "Unused" Variables In A View Model Get Passed To The Client In MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say i've got the following absurd viewmodel in a MVC application.

```
public class Absurd
{
  public string WelcomeMessage {get; set;}
  public string PlainTextAdminPassword {get; set;}
}
```

And this is the entirety of my view

```
<div>@Model.WelcomeMessage</div>
```

Let's assume that both my WelcomeMessage and PlainTextAdminPassword are populated in a controller.

Is PlainTextAdminPassword going to be sent to the client anywhere? Or does MVC only send portions of the ViewModel that are referenced in the View?

Comment: "*i've got the following absurd viewmodel…*". I agree. Having setters on a viewmodel in MVC is absurd ;)

Comment: @DavidArno Can you explain why you think that? Would a big constructor be better for some reason?

Comment: @neilsimp1, the view should only ever read from the viewmodel. It should not be modifying it. Therefore why have (public) setters? There are various ways you could deal with this: use a getter-only interface and pass that to the view, use a "big constructor" as you suggest, use a builder, have internally accessible setters and separate the logic of constructing the viewmodel into a different assembly to the view. There may be others that I've not thought of, each of which has its own pros and cons

Comment: @DavidArno Fair point. I would probably just *not* set any values on the ViewModel from the View, but it is a good argument I had never thought of. I really like the idea of "separate the logic of constructing the viewmodel into a different assembly".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The razor view is passed a reference to the Model, which is used to generate the HTML, which is sent to the client.

The Model and its properties are not sent to the client unless you render them out in some way

Answer (score -6):

The programming precisely determines what *will* be passed, out of what *could be* passed.

Since your Model prescribes that `PlainTextAdminPassword` is `public,` this means that it, also, *"could be* passed," and "the model knows not where!"

(If you're not 100%-comfortable with that, "don't make it `public`!")

Comment: Not having properties as public tends to defeat the purpose of having them in a model to begin with. Unless they are used as part of another public property, but then _that_ becomes the same "issue" as if the password itself had been public.

Comment: `Since your Model prescribes that PlainTextAdminPassword is public, this means that it, also, "could be passed,"` "could" is not an answer to the posted question since OP gave a precise example of where the password field is not actually used on the view. In that case, the answer is **no**.